# ASP.Net C# gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with a linkbutton inside a `<HeaderTemplate>`. There is an event handler for a click on this button. Now if I bind data to the gridview on every `Page_Load` event, then this event fires. But if I bind data to the gridview inside `if (Page.IsPostBack == false)`, then this event doesn't fire.

Is it that after the pageload it realizes there is no data in the gridview hence ignore events generated from the grid?

How do I slove the problem ?

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: I am binding the grid in pageload:  if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bindgrid();

Comment: Post your Page_Load function and the LinkButton_Click function

Comment: Are you setting the CommandName and CommandArgument of your linkbutton and catching the RowCommand event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LinkButton` [behaves like a `Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx)

> The LinkButton control has the same appearance as a HyperLink control, but has the same functionality as a Button control.

That means it triggers a postback when clicked.  So the only way to get the click event to fire, is to wire up the handler if `Page.Postback=true`.  (Keep in mind that since HTTP is stateless, if you wire up an event handler on the initial page load, it won't "remember" upon postback.)

Comment: Alternatively, add the `Button_Click` event handler to the LinkButton in the markup page inside the Gridview, intead of specifying it in the `ItemDataBound` event (or wherever it's being set now)